# Node.js Pun Generator

Tags: javascript, strings

Longtime lurker here. I'm making a pun generator in JavaScript, and I was looking for some feedback/guidance. I don't have much experience building applications with Node, and so a lot of my code feels a bit like rambling. This class is meant to be used like so:

```
let p = new Phrase("The dog likes cheese.")
p.generatePun().then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
})
```

Specifically, I think the web api call could be structured better, but I don't quite know how. I'd appreciate any feedback!

**Phrase.js**

```
const util = require("./util.js");
const wordsApi = require("./rhymeApi.js");

const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

class Phrase {
    constructor(string, badwords = ["the", "on"]) {
        this.tokens = string.split(" ");
        this.badwords = badwords;
    }

    generatePun() {

        let nonBadWordsIndices = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tokens.length; i++) {
            if (!this.badwords.includes(this.tokens[i].toLowerCase())) {
                nonBadWordsIndices.push(i)
            }
        }



        let replaceIndex = util.getRandomElement(nonBadWordsIndices);
        let wordToBePunned = this.tokens[replaceIndex];

        const isCapitalized = wordToBePunned[0] === wordToBePunned[0].toUpperCase();
        const isAllCaps = wordToBePunned === wordToBePunned.toUpperCase();
        const punctuation= wordToBePunned[wordToBePunned.length - 1];
        const isPunctuated = !letters.includes(punctuation);

        if (isPunctuated) {
            wordToBePunned = wordToBePunned.slice(0, wordToBePunned.length - 1)
        }

        return wordsApi.getRhyme(wordToBePunned).then((rhymes) => {
            let rhyme = util.getRandomElement(rhymes).word;
            if (isCapitalized) {
                rhyme = rhyme.replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase())
            }
            if (isAllCaps) {
                rhyme = rhyme.toUpperCase();
            }
            if (isPunctuated) {

                rhyme = rhyme + punctuation
            }



            let punnedPhrase = this.tokens.slice();
            punnedPhrase.splice(replaceIndex, 1, rhyme);
            return punnedPhrase.join(" ")

        }).catch((err) => {
            return "Error in generating pun: " + err;
        });

    }

    toString() {
        return this.tokens.join(" ");
    }
}

module.exports = Phrase;
```

**util.js**

```
let getRandomElement = (array) => {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}

//returns random int in [0, stop)
let getRandomIntInRange = (stop) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*stop)
}


module.exports = {
    getRandomElement,
    getRandomIntInRange
}
```

**rhymeApi.js**

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://api.datamuse.com',
    json: true
}


let getRhyme = (word) => {
    let rhymeOptions = Object.assign({}, options);
    rhymeOptions.uri += '/words?rel_rhy=' + word;
    return rp(rhymeOptions)
}




module.exports = {
    getRhyme
}
```

Comment: I did this mistake as well - using `let` everywhere instead of `const`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly nitpicks, there really isn't anything blatantly wrong with your code. Good work!

- In `util.js`, `getRandomElement` could use `getRandomIntInRange` - since it isn't used anywhere else, if `getRandomElement` doesn't use it, it should be dropped.
- Avoid unnecessary mixing of `let` and `const`. Both `nonBadWordsIndices` and `replaceIndex` are not reassigned but for some reason `let` is used instead of `const` while you use `const` elsewhere. (Also in `util.js` and `rhymeApi.js`)
- What should happen if the empty string is passed as your phrase? I suspect current behavior isn't desired.
- Swallowing errors is bad 99% of the time. Libraries that swallow errors make logging errors to be able to quickly discover the problem and fix it much more difficult.
- It may not be required for this use case, but when building URLs, you should always use `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent` as required to avoid problems like trying to get rhymes for words containing `&`. This is especially important if it is to be used in a web application.

The following points are more my personal preference than objectively wrong.

- If supported by your environment, prefer destructuring to `Object.assign`. (Also, why is the `/words?rel_rhy=` appended here instead of being stored in the options object? There might be a good reason, but it's something to consider)

  ```js
  let getRhyme = (word) => {
      return rp({
          ...options,
          uri: options.uri + '/words?rel_rhy=' + encodeURIComponent(word)
      })
  }
  ```
- Async functions are great! Use them instead of explicitly using promises if possible.
- `isPunctuated` would be more clearly defined with `/[a-z]$/i.test(wordToBePunned)`, similarly, `isCapitalized` could be defined as `/^[A-Z]/.test(wordToBePunned)` These also seem like great utility methods to me, I would likely move them to a utils file if they are used anywhere else in your codebase - and maybe even if they aren't to ensure that if you need them anywhere else you don't end up forgetting you already did the work and rewriting them.
- If `isAllCaps` is true, then `isCapitalized` must also be true, I would prefer to check `isCapitalized` only if `isAllCaps` is false when modifying the returned word.
- Avoid double negatives, it makes code not non-harder to read. `nonBadWordsIndices` is equivalent to `goodWordsIndices`